# Variadic template: inline pattern expansion

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

C++ variadic templates can use patterns where you can repeat blocks surrounding the variadic argument, like so:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
struct MyStruct : seq<pair<Other, Args>...>

MyStruct<X, Y> // expands to seq<pair<Other, X>, pair<Other, Y>>
```

However, as far as I can tell, all these pattern expansions require (and retain) an enclosing block. I'm looking to expand a pattern *inline*, like this:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
struct MyStruct : seq<???Other, Args???...>

MyStruct<X, Y> // expands to seq<Other, X, Other, Y>
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fancy doing meta-programming yourself, you can accomplish the behaviour with four utility overloads.

Like another answer pointed out, the key is concatenating `seq` types, so our utilities will do just that. The important thing to understand is that meta-programming is primarily functional in nature, so the tools will be recursion and pattern matching (all during overload resolution). Here are the overloads:

```
namespace detail {
    auto seq_concat() -> seq<>&;

    template<typename... Args>
    auto seq_concat(seq<Args...>&) -> seq<Args...>&;

    template<typename... Args, typename... Brgs>
    auto seq_concat(seq<Args...>&, seq<Brgs...>&) -> seq<Args..., Brgs...>&;

    template<class Seq, class... Seqs>
    auto seq_concat(Seq& s, Seqs&... ss) -> decltype(seq_concat(s, seq_concat(ss...)));
}
```

The first three are our "base case". When concatenating zero to two `seq`s, we lay out explicitly what type we should get, while the final overload is our general case. To concatenate a list of three or more "seq-like" types, is to concentrate the elements in the list tail, then take that result and concatenate it with the list head.

Now we can write the utility you need, because to create a `seq<Other, A, Other, B>` we may just concatenate `seq<Other, A>` with `seq<Other, B>`, and in if we need more types, we can do pack expansion on `seq<Other, Args>...` and concatenate all of those.

```
struct Other;
template<typename... Args>
using seq_interleave_with_other = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(detail::seq_concat(std::declval<seq<Other, Args>&>()...))>::type;
```

We create a pattern `std::declval<seq<Other, Args>&>()...` to "give us references to objects" we can use in an unevaluated context, then invoke `detail::seq_concat(...)` on the pattern. The return type is (almost) what we need, because our utilities added references for simplicity of implementing them. A quick trip through `std::remove_reference` and we are done. To use it, just write:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct MyStruct : seq_interleave_with_other<Args...>
{};
```

[Here's everything in a live example to play with](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:4,endLineNumber:28,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:26,selectionStartColumn:4,selectionStartLineNumber:28,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:26),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Args%3E+struct+seq%3B%0A%0Anamespace+detail+%7B%0A++++auto+seq_concat()+-%3E+seq%3C%3E%26%3B%0A%0A++++template%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0A++++auto+seq_concat(seq%3CArgs...%3E%26)+-%3E+seq%3CArgs...%3E%26%3B%0A%0A++++template%3Ctypename...+Args,+typename...+Brgs%3E%0A++++auto+seq_concat(seq%3CArgs...%3E%26,+seq%3CBrgs...%3E%26)+-%3E+seq%3CArgs...,+Brgs...%3E%26%3B%0A%0A++++template%3Cclass+Seq,+class...+Seqs%3E%0A++++auto+seq_concat(Seq%26+s,+Seqs%26...+ss)+-%3E+decltype(seq_concat(s,+seq_concat(ss...)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+Other%3B%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Ausing+seq_interleave_with_other+%3D+typename+std::remove_reference%3Cdecltype(detail::seq_concat(std::declval%3Cseq%3COther,+Args%3E%26%3E()...))%3E::type%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same%3Cseq_interleave_with_other%3Cfloat,int,char%3E,+seq%3COther,float,Other,int,Other,char%3E%3E::value,+%22%22)%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Args%3E+struct+seq%7B%7D%3B%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+MyStruct+:+seq_interleave_with_other%3CArgs...%3E%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++%0A%7D+%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g493,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-pedantic-errors+-Wall+-Wextra+-Og%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+4.9.3+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: Huh, hacking function overloads for pattern matching? Super clean; I definitely need to learn more about C++ meta-programming.

Answer (score 4):

Tested with gcc 12:

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...> class seq;
class Other;

template<typename T> struct tuple_2_seq;

template<typename ...Args>
struct tuple_2_seq<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<Args>...>> {

    typedef seq<Args...> type;
};

template<typename ...Args> struct add_other
    : tuple_2_seq<decltype(
                  std::tuple_cat(std::declval<
                      std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<Other>,
                         std::reference_wrapper<Args>>>()...)
              )> {};

static_assert( std::is_same_v< typename add_other<int, float>::type,
           seq<Other, int, Other, float>>);
```

So, with all of that in place you'll want to try your luck with

```
template<typename... Args>
   struct MyStruct : typename add_other<Args...>::type {
 // ...
}
```

In hindsight using a plain pointer instead of `std::reference_wrapper` would've also worked, but what's done is done.